# Add class to first four posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wanting to add a class to the first four posts within my WordPress loop.

This is the code I have so far but it seems to be adding the class to all of my posts

```
<?php 
$c = 0;
$class = '';
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
    $c++;
    if ( $c == 1 || $c == 2 || $c == 3 || $c == 4 ) $class .= ' before-load';
?>

<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?> 

<article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="thepost<?php echo $class; ?>">
```

I havn't added the closing tags in this example of the code cos, well there is no point :)

Thanks in advance guys

/* EDIT */

Right, new problem, because I am running an AJAX script that is pulling the posts from essentially the next page, which is causing the count to reset. See below for image

[image]

Comment: Don't concatenate your `$class` string, only assign - now your 4th item will have 4 times the same class - and assign an empty string if the condition is not met. And `$c <= 4` would read a lot easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

For one you're not resetting the class variable inside the loop, so it still contains the class from the previous iteration, you need to do this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
    $class = '';
    $c++;
    if ( $c == 1 || $c == 2 || $c == 3 || $c == 4 ) $class .= ' before-load';
?>
```

Secondly, the code could be written much more succinctly like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
    $class = '';
    $c++;
    if ($c <= 4) $class = ' before-load';
?>
```

Comment: Your code makes more time than my one, as every time you need to assign blank value first and then override for first four loop.

Comment: I have just edited the original question, as I stumbled upon a new problem with it. Let me know what you think